# iOS Voip push issue

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications, voip

I have a strangest bug ever

I have VOIP pushes integrated to the app

And for one user app do not receive pushes

Same ipa, same certs, backend do sends pushes, and seems they'r lost somewhere in between my app and Apple's push service

So

1. Can a push payload play a role here? If it's too big or malformed?
2. Is it possible to get the status of requested push notification from apple?
3. Does anyone have similar issues?

Current payload

> {
>      "aps":{
>         "alert":"test",
>         "approvalMessageId":0,
>         "badge":0,
>         "category":"ACTIONABLE",
>         "content-available":1,
>         "subtype":"SomeType",
>         "type":"SomeType"
>      }
>   }

All help appreciated

iOS 11.3

Comment: i use silent push notifications

{   "aps" :     {
"alert" : "test",
"approvalMessageId" : 0,
"badge" : 0,
"category" : "ACTIONABLE",
"content-available" : 1,
"subtype" : “SomeType",
"type" : “SomeType"
}
}

Comment: My be that user had off his notifications, or he is not allowing to notifications.

Comment: thing is if the user logs in under another account to the same app - it works